# generic class of enum, number of values

Tags: java, generics, enums

How do I find out, how many values my enum has in this example:

```
public class Analyser<C extends Enum<C>>{
  private long[] dist;
  public Analyser() {
    super();
    dist = new long [C.getEnumConstants().length];
  }
}
```

The last line does not work.

Comment: You cannot access a generic type. It's not a variable.  If the constructor took in a reference to the enumeration, then you could find the length.

Comment: @JustinKSU Enum itself is declared as `public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass in the class literal of the enum:

```
public Analyser(Class<C> enumType) {
    super();
    dist = new long [enumType.getEnumConstants().length];
}

...

Analyser<MyEnum> analyser = new Analyser(MyEnum.class);
```

This is because `C` has no meaning at runtime due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: This works. Thank you. How would I declare the class instead, if I just want to have an arbitrary enum as a private field?

Comment: @ratatosk Not totally clear on what you're asking. Do you want to declare variables of the generic enum constants? They would just have type `C`. Here `getEnumConstants()` returns a `C[]` for example.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the last line cannot be compiled. You need `Class` instance to do this. Here is a modified version of your code:

```
public class Analyser<C extends Enum<C>>{
  private long[] dist;
  public Analyser(Class<C> clazz) {
    super();
    dist = new long [clazz.getEnumConstants().length];
  }
}
```

I however cannot exactly understand why do you extends your class from `Enum`. If you know the enum class at development time you can just say `MyEnum.values().length`.

If you want to write generic code that checks how many values does any enum have you can just write an utility method like:

```
  public static int enumSize(Class<C extends Enum<C>> clazz) {
    return clazz.getEnumConstants().length];
  }
```